# Extra variables lead to segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

In the following code, I have two structs.

The first one is `book` which describes the number of pages of the book using `page`.

The second one is `library` which holds all the books using a pointer `books`, with the parameter `num_book` which tells the total number of books of the library.

The program can be compiled and run perfectly fine, and the `printf` result is OK.

But when I added the extra variable (e.g. `int x = 1;`) as shown in the code. I can still compile the program, but running the executable gives segmentation fault.

I have no idea why it is the case since everything seems to initialized properly. Thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int page;
} book;

typedef struct {
    int num_book;
    book *books;
} library;


int main() {
    library *my_library;
    int n = 5; // number of books in the library

    // extra variable not used
    // uncomment it gives segmentation fault
    // int x = 1;

    my_library->num_book = n;

    my_library->books = (book *) malloc( (my_library->num_book) * sizeof(book) );

    for(int i = 0; i < my_library->num_book; i++){
        my_library->books[i].page = i+10;
        printf("Book %d\n"
               "Number of pages = %d\n",
               i, my_library->books[i].page);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, edited now

Comment: "everything seems to initialized properly" ironically the problem is exactly with uninitialized variable.

Comment: That's why you don't ignore warnings... `-Wall -Werror`

Comment: @bolov oh haha, how stupid I am....

Comment: @K_inverse it's not that you are stupid. Far from it. It's that I found it ironically funny.

Comment: But, why the program can still run when I comment `int x = 1` in the above flaw code?

Comment: What happens in the flawed code is undefined behavior, so there's no guarantee about what happens. It's possible that the `int x = 1` (or lack thereof) changed the stack in a way that causes/avoids the memory corruption leading to the crash.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line after declaration of `my_library`

```
my_library = malloc(sizeof(*my_library));
```

Answer (score 2):

In `C`, you must allocate memory for your struct manually using `malloc`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int page;
} book;

typedef struct {
    int num_book;
    book *books;
} library;


int main() {
    library *my_library = (library *) malloc(sizeof(library));
    int n = 5; // number of books in the library

    // extra variable not used
    // uncomment it gives segmentation fault
    int x = 1;

    my_library->num_book = n;

    my_library->books = (book *) malloc( (my_library->num_book) * sizeof(book) );

    for(int i = 0; i < my_library->num_book; i++){
        my_library->books[i].page = i+10;
        printf("Book %d\n"
               "Number of pages = %d\n",
               i, my_library->books[i].page);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2):

In

```
    library *my_library;
    /* ... */
    my_library->num_book = n;
 // ^^^^^^^^^^ junk here
```

`my_library` has not been assigned (or initialized with) a usable value.